# message.member.displayAvatarURL(); is not a function

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to add a command to my bot, said command will display the avatar of whoever is mentioned. For example 
**>pfp @user1** would display user1's avatar.

However my code is returning an error of  *message.member.displayAvatarURL(); is not a function*

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if(member){
        message.member.displayAvatarURL();
    }
```

What would be the appropriate syntax to execute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=defaultAvatarURL) is a function on [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), not [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

You can either [get the user from the member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) like this:

```js
message.member.user.displayAvatarURL();
```

or just directly use the [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) property:

```js
message.author.displayAvatarURL();
```